# C: Print Horizzontal, vertical and oblique values of a point in an array

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

Excuse me for any grammatcal errors.

I'll try to explain which my problem is as good as I can.

I'm working on a 2 dimensional array, starting from a point of the array I should print the two horizzontal, vertical and oblique nearby cells.

[image: image of what I want to do]

The yellow cell is the start point, the red and grey cells are the cells that I have to print.

The solution I have found is that of making 4 different algoritms: 1 that prints the horizzontal cells, another one that prints the vertical cells, another one that prints the oblique cells (by right to left) and another one that prints the oblique cells (by left to right).

So I am solving the problem as if I were working with vectors, I thing that this is a really bad solution.

Example of the horizzontal print:

```
int startPos=0; 
int counter=5; //Five and not four, because it includes the start point that hasn't to be printed

if(column >= 2) startPos = column - 2;
else counter -= (2-column);
for(i=0; i<counter; i++){ 
    if(startPos + i != column){ //the start point hasn't to be printed
        printf("m-array[%d][%d] ", row, startPos + i);
    }
}
```

I go back of two from the start point and I print the next four cells.

Comment: It might not be the prettiest solution, but it is the most efficient.
Why do you think it's a really bad solution?

Do you prefer a more mathematical solution, which is less efficient, and runs over the entire 2-d array?

Comment: What's the question? Why do you think this code is bad? And define "bad", execution speed, readability or what?

Comment: The code isn't a bad code, but I think that a good solution should be short and efficient, this is efficient but really long. 4 different algorithms to make just one thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the 4 "different" algorithms to be 1, you just need to find what logic is shared between them, and make a function that implements it.

That shared part is that they all print a single line. Each line starts in a different place, and prints in a different direction. I called this function **printLine**.

Note, that the function I made can work with both statically and dynamically allocated arrays.

You can implement it differently. Specifically, you can combine both of the *for* loops and add a test to prevent the main cell from being printed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int isInBounds(int rows, int cols, int y, int x) {
    return (y >= 0) && (y < rows) && (x >= 0) && (x < cols);
}

void printLine(int *array,          // pointer to start of the array
               int rows, int cols,   // amount of rows and columns
               int count,            // how many steps before and after the given cell
               int posY, int posX,   // the position of the cell to print around
               int dirY, int dirX) { // the direction to advance each time
    int y = posY - count * dirY;
    int x = posX - count * dirX;
    int i = 0;

    // loop till we get to the given cell
    // increase y and x according to dirY and dirX
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++, y += dirY, x += dirX) {
        if(isInBounds(rows, cols, y, x)) {
            // don't print if this cell doesn't exist
            printf("Array[%d][%d] = %d\n", y, x, array[y * cols + x]);
        }
    }

    y = posY + dirY;
    x = posX + dirX;
    // loop count times, starting 1 step after the given cell
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++, y += dirY, x += dirX) {
        if(isInBounds(rows, cols, y, x)) {
            // don't print if this cell doesn't exist
            printf("Array[%d][%d] = %d\n", y, x, array[y * cols + x]);
        }
    }
}

void main(void) {
    int rows = 5;
    int cols = 8;
    int array[rows][cols]; // array is uninitialized
    int count = 2; // you wanted to print 5 without middle, which means 2 from each side
    int posY = 2;
    int posX = 3;

    /*************************
    * initialize array here */
    int i = 0;

    for(; i < rows * cols; i++) {
        *(((int *)array) + i) = i;
    }
    /************************/

    printLine((int *)array, rows, cols,
              count,
              posY, posX,
              1, 0); // move 1 row down

    printLine((int *)array, rows, cols,
              count,
              posY, posX,
              0, 1); // move 1 column to the right

    printLine((int *)array, rows, cols,
              count,
              posY, posX,
              1, 1); // move 1 row and column, so down and right

    printLine((int *)array, rows, cols,
              count,
              posY, posX,
              -1, 1); // same as last diagonal but now up and right
}
```

Comment: The algorithm may be fine, even if you can "clip" the boundaries before the loops, but It should be `int main(void)`. Also, why do you declare `array` as a 2 dimentional Variable Length Array if you are going to use it in all of your functions as a monodimensional array?

Comment: I don't really care what main's return value / type is, since this is just an example that can be compiled (gcc). As for using a 2 dimensional array, it doesn't really matter, since I made the function work with whatever kind of array, as long as it's continuous in memory.